# How to display a twig date in french

Tags: symfony

In my twig view I want to display a date:

```
{{ match.date|date("l d F - H:i") }}
```

This date is displayed in english:

`Wednesday 15 June - 15:30`

I would like to display it in french...

I tried to add `setlocale(LC_TIME, "fr_FR");` before to call the view but the date is still displayed in english...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `date` filter in Twig is not well suited for localized date formatting, as it is based on PHP's `DateTime::format`. One option would be to use the `localizeddate` filter instead, provided by the [Intl Extension](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/intl.html).

This extension is not delivered on a default Symfony installation. You will find it in the official Twig extensions repository :

```
composer require twig/extensions
```

Then, just declare this extension as a service in `services.yml` for instance :

```
services:
    twig.extension.intl:
        class: Twig_Extensions_Extension_Intl
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Comment: here is the link to the documentation : http://twig-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intl.html

Answer (score 6):

You can work with [hash](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#literals) (key-value array) and match it with the date object you are manipulating.

For example, to get the day of the week of today in words:

```
{% set trans_day_hash = { 
        "Monday": "Lundi", 
        "Tuesday": "Mardi", 
        "Wednesday": "Mercredi", 
        "Thursday": "Jeudi", 
        "Friday": "Vendredi", 
        "Saturday": "Samedi", 
        "Sunday": "Dimanche" 
    } 
%}
{{ trans_day_hash["now"|date('l')] }}
```

Answer (score 5):

I am using [`format_datetime` twig filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/format_datetime.html) with `locale` and `pattern` arguments as follow:

```
{{ service.date|format_datetime(locale='fr',pattern="EEEE dd MMMM YYYY") }}
```

which outputs for example:

```
vendredi 27 novembre 2020
lundi 02 novembre 2020
vendredi 30 octobre 2020
```

[see this resource](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/#datetime-format-syntax) for date pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Another good practice is:

```
{{ match.date|date("l")|trans }}
```

This way you can translate using your prefered translation file.